# How does Eclipse decide to add a new <folderInfo> to a .cproject file?

Tags: eclipse

I have noticed that sometimes when I am adding new .c and .h files to my project, Eclipse will decide to create a new folderInfo section.   This will mean that build option changes I make to the project settings will only get applied to the folderInfo with the resourcePath=""

```
<folderInfo id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.config.gnu.cross.exe.debug.887144602." name="/" resourcePath="">
                    <toolChain id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.exe.debug.999539370" name="Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.exe.debug">
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix.22516938" name="Prefix" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="arm-none-eabi-" valueType="string"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.mcu.2075272782" name="Mcu" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.mcu" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="STM32L475VGTx" valueType="string"/>
...
```

And not get applied to the build of files associated with the new folderInfo.

```
 <folderInfo id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.config.gnu.cross.exe.debug.887144602.988583928" name="/" resourcePath="Middlewares/Third_Party">
                    <toolChain id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.exe.debug.1946714111" name="Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cross.exe.debug" unusedChildren="">
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix.22516938" name="Prefix" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.prefix" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="arm-none-eabi-" valueType="string"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.mcu.2075272782" name="Mcu" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.mcu" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="STM32L475VGTx" valueType="string"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.board.209220969" name="Board" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.board" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="STM32L475VG" valueType="string"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.instructionSet.422950132" name="Instruction Set" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.instructionSet" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.instructionSet.thumbII" valueType="enumerated"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.fpu.1863501920" name="Floating point hardware" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.fpu" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.fpu.fpv4-sp-d16" valueType="enumerated"/>
                        <option id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.floatabi.1488937056" name="Floating-point ABI" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.floatabi" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="fr.ac6.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.floatabi.hard" valueType="enumerated"/>
                        <targetPlatform archList="all" binaryParser="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ELF" id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.targetPlatform.gnu.cross" isAbstract="false" osList="all" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.targetPlatform.gnu.cross"/>
                        <tool id="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.1521579315" name="MCU GCC Compiler" superClass="fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.compiler.684170490">
                            <option id="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths.1769074545" name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths" valueType="includePath">
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}&quot;"/>
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/Inc}&quot;"/>
 ...
```

How can I prevent new folderInfo sections from being created, or how can I apply my changes to both folderInfo sections without manually editing the .cproject file?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure why this happens, but wanted to post my work around.

Find the top level folder that is causing the issue, and then right click on it and go to "Resource Configurations">"Reset to Default".  Normally this "Reset to Default" is greyed out, but when eclipse has generated a new folderInfo section this option is black/can be selected.

[image]

Comment: This post really helped me. This is not a negligible issue. I had problems compiling and wasted 3 hs until I looked into .cproject and then read this post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me a lot today and I want to add more info.
I wasted 3 hs trying to find out a compilation error that told me the compiler couldn't find a header file.
I had added the correct include folders in [right-click project]->C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols -> includes (for GNU C++).
Still the compiler's preprocessor couldn't find the header files.

I had done exactly what @rose described: I created a new file in the src folder and then I realized I had to add two folders to the include path (-I). I did it.
However the compiler kept failing.

In the .cproject there was two "folderInfo id" sections for the same "configuration artifactName"

One of the "folderInfo id" sections was specifically for:

```
name="/" resourcePath="src"
```

Then I realized that whenever I changed the include paths in "Paths and Symbols" the new **folderInfo id** never changed.
Finally I run into this post and I did exactly what it said. I went to src folder, right click, "Resource Configurations", and "Reset to Default..." was enabled. I clicked and reset to defaults. That was the only folder for which "Reset to Default..." was enabled.
Then in .cproject the non-modifiable **folderInfo id** disappeared and I was able to compile without the same problem (I got new errors :) )

Here I'm adding the differences between the two **folderInfo id** sections. This was the correct one that had the changes:

```
    <storageModule moduleId="cdtBuildSystem" version="4.0.0">

        <configuration artifactName="${ProjName}" buildArtefactType="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe" buildProperties="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType=org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe,org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildType=org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildType.debug" cleanCommand="rm -rf" description="" id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.exe.debug.43054842" name="Debug" optionalBuildProperties="org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher.containerbuild.property.selectedvolumes=,org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher.containerbuild.property.volumes=" parent="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.exe.debug">
                                
            <folderInfo id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.exe.debug.43054842." name="/" resourcePath="">
                                        
                <toolChain id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.exe.debug.330192629" name="Linux GCC" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.exe.debug">
                                                
                    <targetPlatform id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.exe.debug.85760128" name="Debug Platform" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.exe.debug"/>

                    <builder buildPath="${workspace_loc:/myprojUnitTest}/Debug" id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.builder.exe.debug.719946717" keepEnvironmentInBuildfile="false" managedBuildOn="true" name="Gnu Make Builder" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.builder.exe.debug"/>
                                                
                    <tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.archiver.base.1032292713" name="GCC Archiver" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.archiver.base"/>
                                                
                    <tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.1002854658" name="GCC C++ Compiler" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug">
                                                        
                        <option id="gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.option.optimization.level.305235605" name="Optimization Level" superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.option.optimization.level" useByScannerDiscovery="false" value="gnu.cpp.compiler.optimization.level.none" valueType="enumerated"/>
                                                        
                        <option defaultValue="gnu.cpp.compiler.debugging.level.max" id="gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.option.debugging.level.702864614" name="Debug Level" superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.option.debugging.level" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="enumerated"/>
                                                        
                        <option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths.332186867" name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="includePath">
                                                                
                            <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="/opt/googletest/googletest/include"/>
                                                                
                            <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/myproj/common}&quot;"/>
                                                                
                            <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/myprojUnitTest/myproj/connector}&quot;"/>
```

And this one the one that needed to disappear:

```
                    <folderInfo id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.exe.debug.43054842.1553324918" name="/" resourcePath="src">
                                            
                    <toolChain id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.exe.debug.645104237" name="Linux GCC" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.exe.debug" unusedChildren="">
                                                    
                        <targetPlatform id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.exe.debug" name="Debug Platform" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.exe.debug"/>
                                                    
                        <tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.archiver.base.1301414938" name="GCC Archiver" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.archiver.base.1032292713"/>
                                                    
                        <tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.311086767" name="GCC C++ Compiler" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.compiler.exe.debug.1002854658">
                                                            
                            <option IS_BUILTIN_EMPTY="false" IS_VALUE_EMPTY="false" id="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths.168615906" name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths" useByScannerDiscovery="false" valueType="includePath">
                                                                    
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="/opt/googletest/googletest/include"/>
                                                                    
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/myproj/pcap}&quot;"/>
                                                                    
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/myproj/common}&quot;"/>
                                                                    
                                <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/myproj/skb}&quot;"/>
```

I had this problem in my Linux, Ubuntu, with Eclipse IDE for C/C++, version 4.14.0. And this is not an embedded system.
I really don't know if this is an error in Eclipse. It seems there is a bug for this created in 2018 and it was never closed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541268